# OpenSSL upgrade to 3.0.0 and now OpenSSH fails in AIX 7.1

Tags: ssh, openssl, sftp, aix

I have recently upgraded the built-in OpenSSL to 3.0.0. All testing after upgrade was working fine but on reboot to finalize changes SFTP and SSH have failed to initiate. I was no longer able to re-connect to the server remotely, which was showing Network error. FTP was working fine, so I know the server have started successfully.

Any idea what might have happened?

Comment: I wonder where you got your OpenSSL 3.0.0, according to https://www.openssl.org/source/ the latest version is 1.1.1.

Comment: the openssl github repository [link](https://github.com/openssl/openssl)

Comment: That states that 3.0.0 is under development. Use a stable version if you can't handle problems with development versions yourself; there's a reason it's called a stable version.

Comment: I would have if the stable version was compatible with Hadoop that the server was being upgraded for. Besides, I had it working on Windows before. Just wasn't sure if it was AIX issue.

Comment: What version of Hadoop could possibly require OpenSSL 3.0.0, which last time I checked isn't even alpha quality yet?

Comment: As the stable binary for Hadoop 3.2.0 doesn't work with the AIX version I was using I have had to compile Hadoop from start, and it just so happens that the stable 1.1.1 version of OpenSSL does not have a function that the source code for Hadoop requires for it to be compiled which led to the above sequence of events. Any more comments would be slightly off topic but as it is on the informative side...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some digging and another SFTP server down issue, it was the fact that in addition to the OpenSSL upgrade, I have had to upgrade the OpenSSH too, as there were common modules that the old OpenSSH version was incompatible with. So it was a case of:

1. Compile the new OpenSSL
2. Compile the new OpenSSH pointing to the new OpenSSL
3. Check the new packages are stable
4. Install/Upgrade OpenSSL to the new version
5. Install/Upgrade OpenSSH to the new version